# Finding a function that is harmonic in an annulus,

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, harmonic-functions, laurent-series

The problem statement is:

Suppose that the real series $∑_0^{∞} a_n$ and $∑_0^{∞} b_n$ converge absolutely.

Part 1

Prove that there is a function $u(r,θ)$ which is harmonic in $1<r<2$ and continuous onto the boundary such that
$$u(1,θ)=∑ancos(nθ)$$

and

$$u(2,θ)=∑bncos(nθ)$$

Part 2

Is $u(r,θ)$ unique?

My work:

We can look at a Laurent series $f(z) = \sum c_nz^n$

$$=\sum c_n r^ne^{in\theta}$$
$$=\sum (a_n + ib_n) r^ne^{in\theta}$$
$$=\sum a_nr^ne^{in\theta} + ib_n r^ne^{in\theta}$$
$$=\sum a_nr^ncos(n\theta)-b_nr^nsin(n\theta)+ i(b_nr^ncos(n\theta)+a_nr^nsin(n\theta))$$

Now I think the goal is to have

$$u(1,\theta) = Re \big( \sum a_nr^ncos(n\theta)-b_nr^nsin(n\theta)+ i(b_nr^ncos(n\theta)+a_nr^nsin(n\theta))\big)$$

$\implies$
$$u(1,\theta) = \sum a_n1^ncos(n\theta)-b_n1^nsin(n\theta)$$

and similarly

$$u(2,\theta) = \sum a_n2^ncos(n\theta)-b_n2^nsin(n\theta)$$

so that, *if* I can show the R.H.S. is some convergent complex series in the annulus 1<|z|<2, then it defines an analytic function in the annulus, and therefore the L.H.S. of the above two equalities must be harmonic in this annulus, as required.

I am stuck on a few things:

Taking the real part as I had shown above gives an extra term in the summand that I don't want - namely, the $b_nsin(n\theta)$ term.  I am guessing that somehow the $b_n$'s must all be zero, but how can I justify this?

Of course, this is *one* harmonic function, $u(r,\theta)$, from *one* analytic function on the annulus.  So, there needs to be some matching of coefficients of the above two, different, Laurent series.  How could I do that?

And, the coefficients have to be chosen, so that the series actually converges in this annulus.  Here's where I know I should use the assumptions that the real series $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ converge absolutely.  Any idea how I can do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Hint: find a formula to cos(ntheta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: To match the $a_n \cos (n\theta)$ and $b_n \cos(n\theta)$, take a suitable combination of the real parts of $z^n$ and $z^{-n}$.

EDIT: If this combination is $u_n(r,\theta) = c_n r^n \cos(n \theta) + c_{-n} r^{-n} \cos(n \theta)$, we need
$$ \eqalign{c_n + c_{-n} &= a_n \cr
            2^n c_n + 2^{-n} c_{-n} &= b_n\cr} $$
 Solve this system of equations for $c_n$ and $c_{-n}$.  Then show
$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} c_n z^n$ converges absolutely and uniformly on $|z| \ge 1$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n$ converges absolutely and uniformly on $|z| \le 2$.

Comment: Hi Professor Israel, I think I want $u(1,\theta) = \sum a_ncos(n\theta) -b_nsin(n\theta)$ and $u(2,\theta) = \sum a_n2^ncos(n\theta) -b_n2^nsin(n\theta)$.  These sums are the real part of some Laurent series $\sum c_nz^n$, with $c_n = a_n + ib_n$.  But I'm not sure where to go from here.  I've tried several different methods.  Do I need knowledge of Fourier series, or is complex analysis enough here? Thanks @RobertIsrael,

Comment: Also, as I wrote in the previous comment, there is an extra term in the summand -- $b_nsin(n\theta)$ and $b_n2^nsin(n\theta)$.  I am guessing the $b_n$'s must be zero, but I'm not sure why...

Comment: I also posted my work as an edit to my question, if you would like to see it -- I would love to get another hint from you :-)  Thanks, @RobertIsrael

Comment: Thanks so much for your edit, Professor Israel.  I had moved on to some Linear Algebra, but am back to revisit this problem now, @RobertIsrael :-)

Comment: Hmm...Professor Israel, the system of equations that you suggest, I think, could give $a_n$, $b_n$ *complex*, whereas I probably need to use the convergence of $a_n$, $b_n$ as real summands.  I wonder whether I should break up $c_n$ into $a_n + ib_n$; I have tried this a few times with no success.  I will see what else I can do; I am possibly just overlooking a much simpler process.  Please feel free to comment :-)  Thanks @RobertIsrael,

Comment: Perhaps we force the $c_n$'s to be real coefficients for all $n$ ...

Comment: Wow...I got it, Professor Israel :-) ... and, of course the $c_n$'s are real, just from looking at the set of equations to solve.  And I was confused about the $a_n$'s and $b_n$'s, thinking that these were also unknown quantities to solve for, too - they are already determined in the beginning of the problem and their series converge absolutely.  Now I just have to show the convergence of this Laurent series in $1<|z|<2$.  Thanks so much for your help, Professor Israel.  Have a great night @RobertIsrael :-)